# Change Administrator privileges to used account

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts, administrator

So I am in my created account of Windows 8 Pro, which has Administrator privileges (as I look in the accounts part in Control Panel). But then accessing/modifying some folders (not even on my System partition) ask me whether I want to Continue, because they require admin privileges. That is kinda' fine.

But the problem I got into is that I once wanted to install a program, which requires first extraction of installation files. This I was not allowed to do, always getting the following error: *A problem occurred... blah blah. Check available space on your computer and the write privileges on the destination folder.* I have space and I get this error wherever I try to extract this... Desktop or some other folders - doesn't matter. So I assume it is because of Administrator privileges.

I can log in in the true system Admin account, but installing every program by logging to that account is kinda' tedious.

I also tried to change the privileges of my user account, while I am logged in into the system admin acc, but the user account is listed as Administrator and the button for "Change privileges" is not clickable...

**UPDATE:**

[image: This is a shot of the Users list in my Control Panel]

[image: This is the error message I get...]

Comment: If your user account is an `Administrator` then you have the same permissions as the `Administrator` account.

Comment: Did you start the installation program with right click/"Run as administrator" to run it with elevated privileges?

Comment: @Ramhound - I added screenshot of the User accounts list in my Control Panel - you can see by yourself that both accounts are listed as `Administrator`. I am using the scratched one. ////

@WernerHenze - Yes, I did `Run as administrator` and still get the problem.

Comment: @Funkycookie - Verify the owner of the target folder.  Make sure the owner is the scratch out one.

Comment: @Ramhound - I checked for this - the owner was `SYSTEM`. I changed it to my account for the whole folder `C:\\Users\theScratcheduser` where the Desktop is contained and all the other folders. (As I am trying to extract it on the Desktop).

Comment: @Funkycookie - If it was owned by `System` that would be the source of the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound - yeah, but I changed it to my user to be the owner and I still get the error...